# DB2 Relational Tables

Tags: sql, schema, db2

Is it possible to create a database such that there are 2 tables across 2 different schemas within the database who reference each other?

I would like to clarify my question with an example.

Consider the tables, `EMPLOYEE (empID, empName, deptId)` and `DEPARTMENT (deptId, deptName)`. We can impose a foreign key constraint on the `EMPLOYEE.deptId`. In this case can I have these two tables across two different schemas and still impose the constraint?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is yes.
DB2 does not require both tables in a foreign key relationship to reside in the same schema.

Answer (score 1):

You mean via foreign keys or in joins?

Sure: Just always prefix the table name with the schema name and a "." (dot). Like so:

```
select t1.id, t2.id from schema1.table1 t1 join schema2.table2 t2 on t1.fid = t2.id
```

Comment: I meant referential integrity by means of a constraint.

Comment: In that case, you will have to elaborate in your question. What are you trying to achieve? How do the tables look? What's the constraint you want to be asserted?